# Custom \listoffigures with images link

Tags: table-of-contents, urls

In me latex document I use the command `\listoffigures` for the list of figures that I have.

My figure code is

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{xamarin.png}
    \caption{Architettura di Xamarin}
    \label{ref:xamarin}
\end{figure}
```

that I refer with `\ref{ref:xamarin}` into the document.
At the end, my list of figure it's this:
[image]

It is possible to add also the link, for each figure? under each description...like this:
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a different caption text for lof using `\caption[text for list]{text under figure}` and add the url to text for the lof.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}
    \caption[GalaxyZoo\newline \url{https://astrobites.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Galaxy-Zoo-Flowchart.png}]{GalaxyZoo}
    \label{ref:xamarin}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! I added \protect before \url because without gives me an error.

Answer (score 2):

For your figure captions use the custom command `\ccaption{Figure caption}{Figure link}`. I have packaged all the necessary components in this command.

To control the appearances of hyperlinks, please see the [`hyperref` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf).

I use this setup most of the time, you may change as suits you:

```
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor={red!50!black},
  citecolor={blue!50!black},
  urlcolor={blue!80!black}}
```

---

Here is your main piece of code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{url}

\def\hhref#1{\href{#1}{#1}}
\def\ccaption#1#2{\caption[#1\newline#2]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\clearpage

\begin{figure}[!tb]
  \centering
  \rule{0.2\textwidth}{0.25\textwidth}
  \ccaption{First figure.}{\hhref{www.figure.com/fig1}}
  \label{fig:fst}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[!tb]
  \centering
  \rule{0.2\textwidth}{0.25\textwidth}
  \ccaption{Second figure.}{\hhref{www.morefigure.com/figII}}
  \label{fig:scd}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

---

[image]

[image]